# What "*#" means after executint a command in PostgreSql 10 on Windows 7?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using PostgreSQL on Windows 7 through the command line.  I want to import the content of different CSV files into a newly created table.

After executing the command the database name appeared like:

```
database=#
```

Now appears like 
`database*#` after executing:

```
type directory/*.csv | psql -c 'COPY sch.trips(value1, value2) from stdin CSV HEADER';
```

What does *# mean?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that you are trying to execute `type directory ...` command within `psql`. It should be executed within `cmd` instead.

Comment: So I thought this was Linux, sorry, but I thought that because you used forward-slash instead of back-slash. What happens if you change your slash around to `directory\*.csv`?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for Linux** and as such doesn't answer OP's question for Windows. I'll leave it up anyway for anyone that comes across this in the future.

---

You accidentally started a [block comment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS) with your `type directory/*.csv`. `type` doesn't do what you think it does. From the `bash` built-ins:

> With no options, indicate how each name would be interpreted if used as a command  name.

Try doing `cat` instead:

```
cat directory/*.csv | psql -c 'COPY sch.trips(value1, value2) from stdin CSV HEADER';
```

If this gives you issues because each CSV has its own header, you can also do:

```
for file in directory/*.csv; do cat "$file" | psql -c 'COPY sch.trips(value1, value2) from stdin CSV HEADER'; done
```

#### Type Command

The `type` built-in command in Bash is a way of viewing command interpreter results. For example, using it with `ssh`:

```
$ type ssh
ssh is /usr/bin/ssh
```

This indicates how `ssh` would be interpreted when you run `ssh` as a command in the current Bash environment. This is useful for things like aliases. As an example for this, `ll` is usually an alias to `ls -l`. Here's what my Bash environment had for `ll`:

```
$ type ll
ll is aliased to `ls -l --color=auto'
```

For you, when you pipe the result of this command to `psql`, it encounters the `/*` in the input and assumes it's a block comment, which is what the `database*#` prompt means (the `*` indicates it's waiting for the comment close pattern, `*/`).

#### Cat Command

`cat` is for concatenating multiple files together. By default, it writes to standard out, so `cat directory/*.csv` will write each CSV file to standard out one after another. However, piping this means that each CSV's header will also be piped mid-stream of the copy. This may not be desirable, so:

#### For Loop

We can use `for` to loop over each file and individually import it. The version I have above, `for file in directory/*.csv`, will properly handle files with spaces. Properly formatted:

```
for file in directory/*; do
    cat "$file" | psql -c 'COPY sch.trips(value1, value2) from stdin CSV HEADER'
done
```

#### References

- [PostgreSQL 10 Comments Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS) (postgresql.org)
- [`type` built-in Manual page](https://www.mankier.com/1/bash#type) (mankier.com)
- [`cat` Manual page](https://www.mankier.com/1/cat)  (mankier.com)
- [Bash looping tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html) (tldp.org)

Comment: Good answer! But unfortunately the question about Win7 ;)

Comment: @Abelisto so it is! Oops lol. I'll note that at the top of my answer and leave it up.